# Java Lombok log4j use different appender

Tags: java, log4j, lombok

How to use different appender just in one class with lombok.

I tried

```
@Log4j(topic = "myAppender")
@Service("myService")
public class DemoServiceImpl implements DemoService {
  ...
}
```

And log4j configuration

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, myConsoleAppender

# settings for the console appender
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# settings for file appender
log4j.appender.myAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.myAppender.File=mylog.log
log4j.appender.myAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d{DATE} %m%n
```

So I want to log everything in myConsoleAppender but all logs in DemoServiceImpl class want to save to file - use myApppender from log4j properties file.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 4):

I just resolved by myself

adding this to log4j properties

```
log4j.category.myAppenderLogger=INFO, myAppender
log4j.additivity.myAppenderLogger=false
```

and log4j anontation correction

```
@Log4j(topic = "myAppenderLogger")
@Service("myService")
public class DemoServiceImpl implements DemoService {
  ...
}
```